# Enable sections sequentially in a fieldset

Tags: html, forms, fieldset

The `<fieldset>` that appears below contains three sections:

1. Criteria1;
2. Criteria2; and
3. Submit button

Currently, all three sections are active and the user is able to click the `"Submit"` button without first making the selections for `"Criteria1"` and `"Criteria2"`.  I want to prevent this behavior.

I want to ensure that my users first make a selection in `"Criteria1"`, at which point `"Criteria2"` becomes enabled and which will now require a selection.  Once the selection is made in `"Criteria2"`, this will then finally enable the `"Submit"` button.

Basically, I need to ensure that my users follow this process,

1. Select Criteria1;
2. Then select Criteria2;
3. Finally, Submit.

Here is the current `<fieldset>`:

```
<fieldset>
    <section>
        <label for="muni">Criteria1</label>
    <div>
        <input id="county_select" type="text"/>
        <input id="county_no" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
    </section>    
    <section>
        <label for="addi">Criteria2</label>        
    <div>
        <input id="add_select" type="text" onblur="rollnum=jQuery('#add_no').val();" />
        <input id="add_no" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>      
    </section>   
    <section>
    <div>
        <button id="year" value="2012" onclick="loadProperty();"  >Submit</button>
    </div>   
    </section>
</fieldset>
```

I think what I need to do is have the 2nd and 3rd sections start out as disabled, and then somehow enable them as a selection is made in the prior section.  I'm just not sure how to do this and would appreciate some guidance.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this purely through HTML is risky.

You will always be able to POST data to the server no matter how your HTML/js validation is set up.

What you want to do is use a scripting lanauage like PHP to regulate this behavoir, so you could begin to say things like this in your code:

```
if((isset($_POST['Criteria1']))&&(isset($_POST['Criteria2'])){}
else{die();}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see where you are coming from.  I am actually using PHP, just still learning it.  I assume your line of code would need to be implemented with other PHP code . . .

Comment: Well there are a couple ways you can do it. If you are using a shared hosting, PHP is usually enabled by default. What you can do, is change the extension on the page you are working on to .php THEN you can add php to your code. HTML will render normally.